# How to list search results in edit mode like a spreadsheet for easy data entry on WordPress platform?

Tags: search-results

I have custom profiles I would like our team to be able to edit directly in the search results display so they don't have to click into each record individually... much like a spreadsheet... to ease data entry.

Answer (score 1):

Can only think of finding the contacts and doing batch update via profile, this will allow you to update the contact like spreadsheet. But its only limited to few contacts at a time